# Hockeyapp send handled error from os x

Tags: macos, crash-reports, xamarin.mac, hockeyapp

I'm using Hockey app for crash reports for my mac osx application (xamarin.mac). 
I need to send handled error message (or stacktrace) from the application. 
I found solution for android with sending feedback programmatically, but when I look at `BITFeedbackActivity.h` here is not such possibility

https://github.com/bitstadium/HockeySDK-iOS/blob/develop/Classes/BITFeedbackActivity.h

is there any solution?

Comment: HockeyApp does not support this

Comment: @Kerni there is no any workaround?

Comment: No there is no workaround.

Comment: thanks for response @Kerni